# JFrame leaking memory?

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, thread-sleep, invokelater

So today I opened Task Manager and saw that my application leaks 200kbs of memory every second. I looked at my main loop:

```
public final void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(27);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Thread curThread = Thread.currentThread();
    long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
    long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / FPS;
    int fps = 0;
    long lastFpsTime = 0;

    while (thread == curThread) {
        if (shouldClose)
        {
            running = false;
            frame.dispose();
            thread = null;
            curThread.interrupt();
            curThread = null;
        }

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
        lastLoopTime = now;
        //double delta = updateLength / ((double)OPTIMAL_TIME);

        lastFpsTime += updateLength;
        fps++;

        if (lastFpsTime >= 1000000000) {
            System.out.println("FPS: " + fps + "");
            fpsLabel.setText("FPS: " + fps);
            lastFpsTime = 0;
            fps = 0;
        }

        if (GuiNewProject.createButton.isEnabled() && createProjectDialogIsOpen)
            if (GuiNewProject.folder.getText().length() == 0 || GuiNewProject.projectName.getText().length() == 0)
                GuiNewProject.createButton.setEnabled(false);

        if (!(GuiNewProject.createButton.isEnabled()) && createProjectDialogIsOpen)
            if (GuiNewProject.folder.getText().length() > 0 && GuiNewProject.projectName.getText().length() > 0)
                GuiNewProject.createButton.setEnabled(true);

        //render();
        fpsDone.setText("FPS: " + fps);

        try {
            if (shouldClose) {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.sleep((lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME) / 1000000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);
}
```

And I can't seem to figure out why it keeps leaking memory?
Any hints or solution to this memory leak would be helpful!

Regards,
tambre

Comment: Please create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem and update your question.

Comment: isn't possible from code_snipped posted here, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: FYI whatever invoked from invokeLater & killed by Thread.sleep(int) stays in JVM memory until Thread.sleep(int) ended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JLabel.setText()` calls repaint, which pushes a `PaintEvent` onto the event queue. Because your loop is stalling the event queue, it grows infinitely. Hence the memory leak.

(`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` runs a Runnable on the EDT. If that runnable never returns, like yours here, then no further events can be processed)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this part of the program:

```
 while (thread == curThread) {
    if (shouldClose)
    {
        running = false;
        frame.dispose();
        thread = null;
        curThread.interrupt();
        curThread = null;
        // HERE
    }
    // ...
 }
```

Question:  What will `thread == curThread` be at the point I labeled "HERE"?

Answer: True.

Question:  And will the loop terminate?

Answer: No!

---

To be brutally honest, this part of your code is a mess.  You seem to be using two or three different mechanisms to attempt to kill ... something.  Finally, you call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this)` which will (I think) just launch another thread to run the Runnable again.  It's just ... incomprehensible.

Comment: @tambre - I think you should probably throw the whole method away and start again!

Comment: The loop *will* terminate, because later it has `if(shouldClose) return;`.

Comment: @RussellZahniser - OK, but it is still a mess.

Answer (score 1):

After commething out these lines:

```
fpsLabel.setText("FPS: " + fps);
fpsDone.setText("FPS: " + fps);
```

The memory leaks seems like plugged.
Why is setText() leaking memory?
Question is kinda answered, but still why?